# Lose focus from element without resetting the browser's vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, webdriver, action

I have created a custom command that loses the focus from current web element, like this:

```
public void LoseFocus()
{
    int? scrollPositionY = Driver.Current.GetIntValueUsingScript("return $(document).scrollTop();");
    this.ClickOnElementsCoordinates(Driver.Current.FindElement(By.TagName("body")), 0, scrollPositionY.Value);
}

public void ClickOnElementsCoordinates(IWebElement element, int positionX, int positionY)
{
    var builder = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(Driver.Current);
    builder.MoveToElement(element, positionX, positionY)
        .Click().Build().Perform();
    builder.Release();
}
```

The problem is that, each time I call the `LoseFocus()` it sets the vertical scroll position to 0. 
**The vertical scroll bar should not change the current position**. How do I achieve this?
I have also tried using javascript only like this 
`ExecuteScript(null, "document.elementFromPoin(0,""+scrollPositionY.Value+"").click();");`

  but the same happens.

**EDIT 1**

At above c# code I'm getting the current vertical scroll bar position. Then I click on 'body' element on coordinates (0 , scroll pos. Y). I was doing that to prevent the scroll bar from changing its current Y coordinates, but still does not work.

**EDIT 2**

Here is also a sample html [sample html](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y98fkp/2/)

Comment: Could you move to another element instead?

Comment: @lloyd Unfortunately that is not an option. There are cases when need to wait for ajax response (happens only when click outside the element).

Comment: so where did you expect or what the pointer to move to ?

Comment: @lloyd I would expect it to stay at the current vertical scroll bar's position, please see _Edit 1_

Comment: Could you include a sample section of html?

Comment: @lloyd please see Edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All logic that I was implemented was correct except I needed to click on `offsetY` not `absoluteY` coordinates, so no need to pass any element (in my case- document).

```
// Wrong
builder.MoveToElement(element, posX, posY)

// Correct, clicking on document's offset
builder.MoveByOffset(posX, posY)
```